# Make background fit to the page grid, without the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a squared background on my page using css (3x3 squares) and add every other element on the page in a way that they can fit such background.

So, after making the background, which divides the screen in 3 columns I made a css grid but I've noticed that there's a slight gap between the grid and the background (even though they both divide the space into 3 columns).

[image]

I was wondering if this issue is caused by the scrollbar, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Can you help me understand how to the background fix the grid?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 700vh;
 
  background: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(20,20, 20, .7) .06em, transparent .06em), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(20, 20, 20, .7) .06em, transparent .06em);
  background-size: 33.3vw 33.3vw;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  
}
.element-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
.element-2 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
.element-3 {
  grid-column-start: 5;
  grid-column-end: 7;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="element-1">element 1</h1>
  <h1 class="element-2">element 2</h1>
  <h1 class="element-3">element 3</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the property `width` in the `body` selector in css. If you set it to 100% it'll take the whole space available including the scrollbar. So to fix this problem you must use `100vw` like this

```
body{
   width: 100vw;
}
```

`vw` means one fraction of the width window, so `100vw` means the whole width of the window. Now the div fraction doesn't have a gap with the background.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't solve the issue unfortunately

Comment: In the `.container` class set `grid-template-columns` to `1fr 1fr 1fr` and delete all the `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end`. You'll get the same result but without the gap